# Error: write after end while node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading the data from Cassandra using the stream() function of https://www.npmjs.com/package/cassandra-driver, I am listing to the events and piping the stream to the response object but I am getting this error

Error: write after end

this is my code

```
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
        res.write('{');
                            stringsToAppendToStream.push('\"Result\":');
                            const responseStream = stringsToAppendToStream.join(',');
                            res.write(responseStream);

                            let streamObject = casssandraClient.stream(generateSQL);
                            // console.log(sstreamObject);
                            streamObject.on('readable', function () {
                                let row;
                                while (row = this.read()) {
                                    console.log(row);
                                    streamObject
                                        .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
                                        .pipe(res);
                                }


                            })

                            streamObject.on('end', function () {
                                console.log('ending')
                                res.write('}');
                                res.end();

                            })
```

I tried the callback suggestion given in some other answer while writing the data but it doesn't solve the issue

```
res.write(messages, function(err) { res.end(); });
```

it seems like issue is while I pipe() the response but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Where does the error occur? Did you single-step through the code with a debugger? What did you find out from those `console.log()`s? Also, you need to post your real code so people can run it on their own machines and see what's going on. I don't mean post all of your code--I mean post enough that people can run it and see the problem. What you've posted doesn't run.

Comment: And *how* did you use that callback suggestion? Where did you put the code for that? And add a link to the answer where you got that suggestion. Don't answer me on any of these questions; update your original post and add all these details.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue and it might be that this solution apply for this particular use case only, we don't have to listen for the 'redable' event instead pipe the stream directly to the response.

```
let streamObject = casssandraClient.stream(sql);

                    streamObject
                        .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
                        .pipe(res, {
                            end: false
                        });

                    streamObject.on('end', function () {

                        res.write('}');
                        res.end();

                    })
```